# Maven surefire can't find testng tests in module

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, maven-3, testng, surefire

Does Maven surefire require a testng.xml file to run testng classes and methods?  I have a multi module reactor setup in maven.  Testng and some custom tools are located on one module and our tests are located on another module.  Our structure is like this

```
/pom.xml
/testng-utils/pom.xml
/testng-utils/src
/tests/pom.xml
/tests/src
```

The tests module has a dependency on testng utils.  testng-utils module brings in testng and hamcrest.  Surefire is a plugin in tests/pom.xml.

I use testng annotations inside my tests, and I don't use an testng.xml file, I realize I'm providing very little information so I'm not expecting anything too in depth for an answer, just maybe a hint as to why my tests aren't being found.

Does anyone use a setup at all similar to this, and invoke testng without the use of a testng.xml file through surefire?  I can try to include more information if anyone wants it if I'm able, but this is for the company I work for so I can't put much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you place your tests under **src/test/java** directory and follow the ***Test.java** naming convention surefire should be able to pick them up without any further configuration.

[Surefire + TestNG](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)

Comment: That's what I thought, there must be something else going on that I need to find.